# An Efficient Way to Load and Update Data from Parse (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I want to fetch data from Parse and save/load data from local databases without using Parse pin/unpin features due to some needs. I have a **timestamp db** (has a column called dbname, and a column called timestamp) and a **actual db** for data on both local and Parse. And my app will first compare the timestamp on local with Parse. If the timestamps are different, then my app will update the local DB. My questions are that: Is this a correct way to improve app's performance (i.e. reduce loading time, any demos on github?)? Where should I implement this? Should I do it in app delegate or in the first view controller? What will the most efficient way to do this? Is there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to read this [Apple iOS developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Getting%20Started)

from the Set up [Set Up](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1)

Try to understand the architecture of the iOS app.